# js как показать в консоли searchParams моего адреса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как показать в консоли параметры моей ссылки
Моя ссылка: http://localhost/real/?filters=do-morya%5B21%5D%7Ckomnat%5B25%5D%7Cprice%5B114_200%5D

Хочу вывести в консоль только параметры, в таком виде: do-morya%5B21%5D%7Ckomnat%5B25%5D%7Cprice%5B114_200%5D

пробую console.log(new URL(window.location.href).searchParams);
но не получается

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

console.log(window.location.search.substring(1));

Answer (score 0):

Так подходит?

```js
const url = new URL('http://localhost/real/?filters=do-morya%5B21%5D%7Ckomnat%5B25%5D%7Cprice%5B114_200%5D');

console.log(url.searchParams.get('filters')); // do-morya[21]|komnat[25]|price[114_200]
```

Подробнее см. методы [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).